# Web2py custom forms and for loop

Tags: python, web2py

I am new to Web2py so i hope this is not too dumb of a question.

i have a database of fruit with boolean values.

obviously this is a long list of fruit so i want them to be formated in columns so i went with a custom form. i also want to group the fruit , ie citrus , berries etc.

my thinking is to create a tuple

```
{{berries = 'strawberries, bilberry, blackberry'}}
```

and then run a for loop to fill in the form fields, so i tried

```
{{for berry in berries:}} 
{{=form.custom.widget[berry] }}
{{pass}}
```

I just get to see a lot of "none", i assume this is because i have the form.custom string wrong but i have tried a few ways to parse it but none seem to work.

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Should my code be in the view or controller?

what is the correct way to pass the variable to get the loop and form to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
berries = 'strawberries, bilberry, blackberry'
```

is not a tuple -- it is just a string. So, your `for` loop is iterating over each letter in the string. If you provide a non-existent key in `form.custom.widget[key]`, it returns `None`. Instead, you want:

```
berries = 'strawberries', 'bilberry', 'blackberry'
```

Comment: Thanks thats got it.
i also added {{=berry}} to label the boxes